# Singular chain of sphere-2

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The textbook by Allen Hatcher gives an example of the simplicial chain of one-dimensional sphere $S^1$ in which there is one vertex $v$ and one edge $e$ and $\partial e=v-v=0$ implying $H_1^\Delta(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. I want to apply this similar procedure to calculate the $H_2(S^2)$ (singular homology group). Then the 2-chain consists of single mapping $\sigma_2:\Delta^2\rightarrow S^2$ with $\partial\Delta^2$ mapped to the north pole $\{N\}$. The 1-chain consists of one single $\sigma_1:\Delta^1\rightarrow\{N\}$ with the 0-chain $\sigma_0:\Delta^1\rightarrow\{N\}$. However, $H_2(S^2)$ is calculated as $0$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}$ since $\partial\sigma_2\neq0$. Could anyone tell me where my mistake takes place? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion between singular and simplicial homology.  If you are computing the singular homology as you claim, then you need to consider the set of *all* possible continuous maps $\Delta^n\to S^2$ as generators of your chain group in each dimension (and there are uncountably many of them!).  So your computation just says nothing about the singular homology group $H_2(S^2)$: you have only computed the boundary of a single singular $2$-simplex, but there are uncountably many more that might contribute to the homology group.

If you instead do mean to compute simplicial rather then singular homology, the problem is that you do not have a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^2$.  Recall that if $\sigma:\Delta^n\to X$ is a simplex in a $\Delta$-complex structure on a space $X$, then $\sigma$ must be injective when restricted to the interior of $\Delta^n$.  This is not true of your $\sigma_1$, and therefore you do not have a $\Delta$-complex structure.

Comment: I really thank for your thoughtful answer and I guess, by your disentanglement, I understand these concepts much more! Thanks a lot!